# Flutter-Firebase Messaging,Data Messages not received in background and terminated state on ios after killing the app and launching it again

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using flutter to develop my app ,  firebase auth for user authentication and firebase messaging for data notifications when app is in background and terminated state.

In IOS,
when app does a fresh firebase authentication and generate a fcm token, notifications are received when app is in background state, but once i kill the app from background , and launch it again , the notifications stop being received by the app until i do a firebase auth verification and generate a new fcm token again.

```
in main.dart file in the main function initializeFirebase function is 
called .

Future initializeFirebase() async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(
    _onAppInTerminatedNotificationHandler, // This Callback must be static
  );

  FlutterError.onError = FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.recordFlutterError;
  FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.setCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled(true);
}

Future<void> _onAppInTerminatedNotificationHandler(
  RemoteMessage message,
) async {
  //await Firebase.initializeApp();

  print('A new terminated Push Notification Received');
  await NotificationManager.instance.showLocalNotification(message);
}
```

Comment: Please share code how message receiving is handled.

Comment: i have updated the description

Comment: When you say "the notifications stop being received by the app", does this still refer to background behaviour? Can you verify from the sending end that the message is delivered?

Comment: i uncommented the await firebase.intializeApp() in onAppInTerminatedNotificationHandler , the notifications are working fine when app is in background but when app is terminated the data notifications are not being passed to the background service , in flutter logs 
i can see 
Submitted Activity com.apple.pushLaunch.bundleid at priorty 6 <private>
push not allowed for <private>
daemon canceling activites :{{
com.apple.pushLaunch.bundleid })